# Merging two files in windows

Tags: merge

I was playing GTA San Andreas and I want to install some mods which require to replace the
*root-directory*\data\script\main.scm and
*root-directory*\data\script\script.img
but I already have a mod which replaces these so I want to combine both the files from both the mods.

Comment: Are these files binary or text?

Comment: The already there file https://easyupload.io/m/tb2czs
The new files that I wanna merge https://easyupload.io/m/a3d0t7
I'm not a very techy user

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't download random files from random websites. Can't you look at the contents of the file to see if it is text or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.